# Unable to modify Sharepoint site on my local machine

Tags: permissions

I just started at a new job and have had my credentials set to administrator.  When I attempt to modify our pages on my local machine, I am only allowed to minimize, close, and delete web parts.  When I access the site via another users PC, I have full capabilities.  This leads me to believe it is a browser issue (i.e. missing addons).  I have sharepoint developer installed on my machine, but no version of visual studio.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what browser/version are you running compared to the other user's machine.

Comment: both are using IE 9  ver 9.0.8112

Comment: Is one running 32 bit and the other running 64 bit by chance?

Comment: Is the URL you are using to access it locally the same as the one you are using to access it remotely?

Comment: both URLs we are using are the same.  and both machines are 64 bit machines.  I found that I can access and modify the site using Firefox and Chrome on my machine.  So the issue only appears to be affecting my IE browser.

Comment: Make sure you are logged in as administrator, as indicated top right of page (assuming default master). May need to re-start IE.

Answer (score 4):

Please verify that the Url is listed in the Local Intranet zone in the local copy of Internet Explorer.  This sounds a lot like IE trimming functionality back for what it thinks is an untrusted site.

Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> Local Intranet -> Sites -> Advanced

Comment: That is exactly what the problem was.  Thank you both very much for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Scott - Don't forget to mark as answer!

Answer (score 1):

Check that your machine doesn't have entries in the hosts file that would override DNS settings:

```
 C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Look for entries matching the url of your intranet:

```
192.168.123.123 intranet
```